# Access 2007 - Hide Text based on check box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database that has a table (Fixture Schedule), a form (Input Fixtures), and two reports (Exterior Fixture Schedule, Interior Fixture Schedule).

For this database, the users will be using the "Input Fixtures" form to add fixtures to the "Fixture Schedule" database.  When they've finished adding data, the "Exterior/Interior Fixture Schedules" take the data in the table and output it in a report that can be printed or exported.

Because of the nature of the table, there will be times where the data in the table for a particular record needs to stay in place, but that record needs to be flagged as "Not Used" for the report.

I've set up the table with a column labeled "Not Used", and the form successfully uses a check box to update a fixture's current "Used/Not Used" status (i.e. when the form says "Not Used", the table says "Not Used" and vice-versa).

However, I would like to have the reports reflect the "Not Used" status in a meaningful manner.

Currently, the reports will show data from the table something like this:

```
F1
Information about fixture
------------------------------------------
Location:  Something
Min/Max:  Something
Dimensions: Something
```

(and so on, one text box per column in the table).

What I would like to do is have the "Not Used" status trigger the Visible status of each text box, and change the "Information about fixture" line's text.  It would then look like this:

```
F1
NOT USED
------------------------------------------
```

(everything below this is hidden)

I've been trying a variety of VBA scripts.  Some have had me try to assign a value to the "Tag" control and use If-Then statements, but it's not working (user error, most likely).

It seems like it should be fairly easy to have the report check the status of the "Not Used" column in the "Fixture Schedule" table and adjust its output based on that, but I'm not having any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you should base your report on a query that excludes the Not Used records.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That would make sense, except that I don't want to fully exclude the records - I just want to have most (not all) of the fields hidden.  This functionality is important, as that data may have to be re-used later.

Comment: I still think that a query might work, have you looked at IIf?

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but it might be tomorrow before I can really dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

In the report:

1. Use query to display to display [Info] or "Not Used", eg:

   Display: IIF(NotUsed, "Not Used", [my info field])
2. Use the Detail Format event to hide fields you don't want displayed, eg:

   Location.visible=not NotUsed (etc)
3. Set Detail section to Can Shrink=True.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  To clarify, you're saying I need to build a query that checks if a fixture is used or not used.  Where do I then put the IIF command?  Is that applied on a per-text box basis, or do I apply it to the whole report?

Also, I don't see a "Detail Format" option in the "event" tab.  Perhaps I'm missing something, though.

Comment: For your report, rather than just basing it on the table, create a query for the report to use. Saving this query also allows you to run the query and test it, without having to run the report, which can be useful. In this query add the fields you want in the report, PLUS, add: Display: IIF([NotUsed], "Not Used", [my info field]) to a new column in the query. Of course, replace the text I've used in square brackets with the correct names of your fields. Then test the query by running it.

Comment: Re (2), in the report design view, click on the Detail section header, and open the properties window (eg, right-click > Properties) . In the property 'On Format', use the combo box to select [Event Procedure]. Then click on the ellipsis (...) at the right hand side to open the VB editor, and Access will create an empty sub for you. In there, add the line: Location.visible=Not [NotUsed] - assuming you have the field Location in the report, and you want to hide it if not used. You will need your field [NotUsed] in the Detail section of the report as well, but you can hide that if you want.